# How to make this parallax scrolling effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey there SO community!

I have two divs. When the user scrolls I want the second div to scroll quicker and start to cover up the first one.
I have somewhat accomplished this; however, my way is innefficient and doesn't work when the user tries to scroll back up.

```js
let divSecond = document.getElementsByClassName("divSecond")[0];
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    let a = parseInt(this.getComputedStyle(divSecond)['top']);
    let b = window.scrollY;
    let c = a - b;
    divSecond.style.top = c + 'px';
});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    --red: #DE0000;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}

.first-div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
.divSecond {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50em;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="first-div"></div>

    <div class="divSecond"></div>

    <script src="Script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Further details are listed below.

How it currently looks (ignore that it's about Hitler it's for a school coding project):

https://streamable.com/afdkpa

If you couldn't tell at the end I was stuck in white because I couldn't go up further because my code don't work.

Honestly a lot of stuff but I think my math is just wrong. Mainly stuff with margin-top, top, adding offsets, multiplying, etc. Just random stuff but im sure my code was wrong.

Comment: hi I changed your "second-div" class name to "divSecond" because it was giving an error on the word "second"

Comment: Yeah, that slipped my mind, these aren't the actual variable names I just quickly changed them to make it easier to read for anyone seeing this post.

Comment: I have never actually done a parallax effect before, but my understanding is that they usually use either background-images, or CSS transform magic.  [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/create-parallax-scrolling-css/) seems like a good resource.  I know it's not an answer to your question, but I do wonder if you might be starting off in a direction that will just make your life more difficult.

Comment: For your specific case, I think it is probably a really bad idea to move the element (second-div) that is introducing the scrollbar to begin with.  When I put all of your code into a fiddle, the first thing that happens is that the second div goes up, the scrollbar disappears, and then you can't scroll at all anymore, which I think is a fundamental flaw with the approach.

Comment: @ZombieKicker7 I think because we can't use dashes ' - '  in variable names in Javascript. We should use underscores ' _ '